# non-www with trailing slash 301 redirect in web.config (Single Redirect)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

How can I 301 redirect my URLs to `non-www equivalent with trailing slash` at the end with only a **single 301 redirect** (avoid redirect chain)? I am using ASP.net 4.5 / C# / Web Project with my routes registered in the `RouteConfig.cs`.

One option is to check the URL in code behind for each page and rebuild the URL, but I prefer letting IIS handle it using Rewrite rules.

As you can see from this image (via chrome, client side), there are two 301 redirects, because in my web.config I have two rules, one for changing to lowercase URL and second to add trailing slash.

[image]

Maybe there is an option in IIS to prevent redirection until all the URL rewrites ran internally. I searched for it, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In web.config (you need to have IIS URL Rewrite module installed)

```
   <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="noslash" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".+[^\/]$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.yourdomain.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="yourdomain.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourdomain.com/{R:0}/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".+\/$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.yourdomain.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourdomain.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

EDIT2: added trailing slash at the end of the url if it doesn't exist

Comment: thanks but I think that's only for www to non-www, the trailing slash is not taken into acount and in a single redirect.

Comment: I've edited the redirect URL, now it adds the trailing slash

Comment: Yeh, but the added slash will only happen  if the url has www. If the URL doesn't have www, it won't append the trailing slash.

Comment: I've edited again, now it will add trailing slash for URLs with or withour www and won't touch URL without www and with slashes

Comment: these rules I have built in IIS for forcing slash and canonicalizing URLs, the issue is that when two rules applied, it causes two 301 redirects on the client side (See the image that I added to my question). I want the IIS to process all the rewriting rules before submitting the correct rewritten URL.